# Detection of periodic patterns using DWT

Tags: r, time-series, wavelet

Is it possible to detect a periodic pattern in a time series using discrete Wavelet Transform?

Is there any package in R to do this job?

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a few packages in R implementing a wavelet transform. For example you could try the [wavelets](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/wavelets/index.html) packages or you could see the cran [time series task list](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/TimeSeries.html) for more possibilities.

However there are simpler options if you are just look for periodic patterns. For example you could use the spectrum function (which uses a Fourier transform) that comes with R or you could look at autocorrelations or partial autocorrelations at various lags using acf and pcf respectively.